# I was wondering why am I getting this error?

Tags: vba, ms-access

(fake entries and file directories)

This is the error I got when trying to run a macro that takes values from a query and assigns them to a bookmark'd location on a word .docx

[image]

this is the line it fails on

```
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Query1", dbOpenDynaset)
```

this is the query that the vba code is taking values from

```
SELECT Table1.ProjectNo, Table1.FirstName, Table1.LastName, Table1.Phone, Table1.ProjectName, Table1.EMail, Table1.Client
FROM Table1
WHERE (((Table1.LastName) Like "*" & [Forms]![Form3]![SearchBox] & "*"));
```

[image]

```
Private Sub Command9_Click()
Dim wApp As Word.Application
Dim wDoc As Word.Document
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset


Set wApp = New Word.Application
Set wDoc = wApp.Documents.Open("C:\Documents\ECORtester.docx")
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Query1", dbOpenDynaset)

If Not rs.EOF Then rs.MoveFirst

Do Until rs.EOF

    wDoc.Bookmarks("Attention").Range.Text = Nz(rs![FirstName], "") & Nz(rs![LastName], "")
    wDoc.Bookmarks("Client").Range.Text = Nz(rs![Client], "")
    wDoc.Bookmarks("Email").Range.Text = Nz(rs![Email], "")
    wDoc.Bookmarks("Phone").Range.Text = Nz(rs![Phone], "")
    wDoc.Bookmarks("ProjectName").Range.Text = Nz(rs![ProjectName], "")
    wDoc.Bookmarks("ProjectNumber").Range.Text = Nz(rs![ProjectNo], "")
    wDoc.SaveAs2 "C:\Documents" & rs!ProjectNumber & "_ECORtester.docx"
    rs.MoveNext
    
Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Your query probably has a parameter and you haven't set that.

Comment: Do you really want to save it as `C:\Documents9_ECORtester.docx` ?

Comment: Should show query SQL, just an image of data output is not much help.

Comment: @June7 I just added the SQL , maybe it can help.

Comment: @brax that error has been removed

Comment: this error? `wDoc.SaveAs2 "C:\Documents" & rs!ProjectNumber & "_ECORtester.docx"` - looks like it's still there to me... you are missing backslash(es).

Comment: @brax I am using a placeholder directory

Answer (score 1):

Recordset based on query object that has undefined/unset dynamic parameter won't work. Instead, base recordset on table and build SQL in VBA.

```
strSQL = "SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE LastName Like "*" & [Forms]![Form3]![SearchBox] & "*"
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSQL, dbOpenDynaset)
```

Using LIKE with wildcard could return multiple clients. If there are multiple people with same/similar last name, they could all be retrieved. If you want only one client, then use unique record ID as filter criteria. A combobox may be more useful than a free-form input textbox. With code, combobox can implement pattern matching and 'filter as you type' functionality but then selection is made from listed items and unique ID is available.

Answer (score 1):

Your `WHERE` clause has a parameter in it that isn't being set.

Define it as a querydef and create the recordset from that.

```
    Dim qdf As QueryDef
    Dim rs As Recordset
    Set qdf = CurrentDb.QueryDefs("Query1")
    qdf.Parameters("[Forms]![Form3]![SearchBox]") = [Forms]![Form3]![SearchBox]
    
    Set rs = qdf.OpenRecordset
```